# Hide List on Dashboard when user login

Tags: woocommerce

i create a user for login to dashboard on my wordpress,but i dont know how to hide List sub menu.i use woocommerce.what should i do to make it done.thank for you help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM2Kk.png)

thank for advance

i dont know how to be done and need help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your active theme functions.php file.

```
// Add custom CSS to WordPress admin footer
function custom_admin_footer_css() {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Your custom CSS styles go here */
        .woocommerce-admin-page.post-type-shop_order ul.subsubsub {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_admin_footer_css');
```

Tested and works

[image]

Comment: thank for you replay,but i dont know why,its not work on my wp.